# How do I detect whether a browser supports popup windows?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, browser

I need to open 2 popup windows when on a desktop device and just 1 single window/tab when on a mobile device, or more specifically a device that doesn't have a notion of detached windows.

Is this possible?

Comment: Never do popups on mobile devices...

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly that eg: Detect whether the browser supports detached windows and if not, don't launch it.